# I'm at a loss coding a generated attack (php in-game attack)

Tags: php, pdo

First off a little background as to what I'm working with & what I've tried. Currently, I have 5 different "Followers" each player in the game can have. Also, I have 7 different weapons to choose from that you can buy. all this information is stored in a DB and is called when I need it. What I'm having trouble doing is coding when a player chooses to attack another player. First I need to calculate which weapons both players own & if they do or do not have enough weapons to cover their followers. obviously not enough weapons the follower without weapons will die without doing any damage. Also, each of the followers has a different amount of HP, as do the weapons that do different amounts of damage. I need to make it so gun priority goes to the strongest followers & that when attacking the weakest attack first. Maybe I am overthinking the whole thing, but I've tried many different things jumping from if-else else if statements, to loops, to messing about with query arrays etcetera. here are the attacker & defender arrays of followers & guns.

```
Array Attacker Followers (me)
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2303292
    [2] => 3530030
    [3] => 2317732
    [4] => 2700217
)


Array Defender Followers (them)
(
    [0] => 3200000
    [1] => 2310000
    [2] => 2420000
    [3] => 1200000
    [4] => 1455000
)
```

```
Array Attack Guns (weakest - strongest)
(
    [0] => 5000
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 2700218
)


Array Defender Guns (weakest - strongest)
(
    [0] => 5000
    [1] => 5000
    [2] => 5000
    [3] => 10000
    [4] => 5000
    [5] => 5000
    [6] => 21170000
)
```

Now I'm not asking for someone to code the entire thing for me, It's just I've been at this for so long I just need a solid example to be pushed in the right direction. I've tried so many different things that range from utter failure to wonky success, but I can't make it to the finish line. Please someone help a brother out. P.S as far as Values go for the damage I don't have anything set in stone I'm just using 10 for hp & 5 for damage.

Answer (score 0):

For the weapons, normally you should have "attack" type and "defence" type. the defence type is for "covering" the followers and the attack type is for yourself.

In a game like this, normally you should also allocate the defence weapons to respective followers. So that the game can determine which followers to die.

Say weapon 1 (defence level is say 500) is allocated to follower 1 (HP is say 5000), weapon (defence level is say 700) is is allocated to follower 2 (HP is say 4000), etc.

Assuming the Gun can target at multiple followers, then when the enemy attacks you , all the followers will get hurt, but the amount of HP reduction can be determined by

1. defence level
2. HP level
3. gun level (of the enemey)

Say gun level is 1000, HP level is 5000, defence weapon level is 700

then
the HP reduction can be

5000 - 1000 + 700.

or if better , you can add a "random" points so that the HP reduction can be less / or more , or other calculations you can imagine , so as to get the game more interesting.

e.g. 5000 -1000 + 700 + random (say from 100 to 300)

But if there is no defence weapon, according to your question then the HP will be immediately reduced to zero and the follower dies.

There are also other things you can add to your game

1. can have potions for increasing the HP back to maximum
2. the system should allow say picking up of new defence / attack weapons.
3. If possible, all the followers should have BOTH attack and defence type weapons
4. after winning a battle, the "level" of the player can be slightly increased, so that the HP can be increased, etc.

Hope that the above can give you some hints.

Comment: I appreciate the idea of your post it is well laid out, but it's overly complex for what I'm trying to achieve for a simple text-based game. In my head what I'm trying to achieve is something more along the lines of "You killed "x" amount of follower 1 & Lost "x" amount of follower one, so on and so on, which I can get, but my problem is its only fol 1 vs fol 1 I want it so if my fol1 kills all of yours. My fol1 moves onto fol2 and down the chain, it goes.

Comment: I see. For sure you can simplify the logics, in your case just use the simple mathematics `HP = original HP + defence point - attacker GUN point`  to determine "you killed x followers", and ignore other points